# Spring MVC Ajax Form POST

Tags: spring, jquery, spring-mvc

Friends

Im trying to understand best way to POST data using Sring MVC form and AJAX

In My code

```
<form:form modelAttribute="ConfigForm" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/channelConfig/voice/save" cssClass="form-horizontal" method="post">
                    <div style="text-align: left;" class="span3 row-fluid">
                    <label><spring:message code="alert.channels.outbound.lines"></spring:message>:&nbsp; </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class = "span3">
                    <div class="input-mini">  
                     <div class="textVal">${alertStatusForm.outboundLines}</div> 
                        <div class="pencil span3 ">
                            <i class="icon-edit icon-large"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="save span3" onclick="submitForm()">
                          <i class= "icon-save icon-large "></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="close span3">
                           <i class= "icon-remove"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                    </div>
                </form:form>
```

Now my submitForm() code is

```
 function submitForm() {
           jQuery.ajax("/monitor/status/save/event/${alertStatusForm.outboundLines}" ,
        {
            type:"POST"
        });    
    }
```

Please let me know if above way is better or suggest a suitable method to post the data

Comment: jQuery have several methods for doing AJAX, like `$.ajax` (what you used) and `$.post`.  The once thing I am not seeing above is how you are serializing the values.  One of the methods you might want to look at is `$.ajaxForm()`, which serializes the form for you and does the AJAX call.  You can also manually serialize the form and post it by using the `serialize()` method on the Form like `$('#ConfigForm').serialize()', and sending that as the data to the ajax call, which is what the `ajaxForm()` is doing.

Comment: Thanks I will use ajaxForm and update